# Complementarity of one-particle and two-particle interference - what it is, and why it is

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

I understand only that this phenomenon makes transmitting of information non-locally impossible. I understand this very vaguely, and most information in the internet are just scientific papers, I couldn't find easily digestible description of this.

I think this question is important for everyone who would like to understand the confusing quantum non-locality - how is non-local action possible, with the communication being impossible. If anyone would describe non-mathematically this phenomenon, it would be very useful in explaining what is going on in the quantum world.

Can it be explained without going too deep into math?

Example papers:

- ["An Inquiry into the Possibility of Nonlocal Quantum Communication"](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.5098.pdf) (BTW, This is really amazing paper for people who want to understand better problem of nonlocal quantum communication, I strongly recommend),
- ["Complementarity of one-particle and two-particle interference"](http://www.academia.edu/1002375/Complementarity_of_one-particle_and_two-particle_interference)

Comment: please make it more clear what you want to know exactly and explain what you already do understand

Comment: I understand only that this phenomenon makes transmitting of information non locally impossible. I understand this very vaguely, and most information in the internet are just scientific papers, I couldn't find easily digestible description of this phenomenon.

Comment: Please can you provide some details about the context of your question. What prompted you to ask it?

Comment: Curiosity :) . I'm just trying to understand the basics of quantum mechanics recently. Currently - the non-locality associated with the entanglement. I read some papers on it, and they were referring to this phenomenon. I understand some things about it, but I don't have a full picture of where this phenomenon comes from.

Comment: Link to the papers you mention?

Comment: Can you just give an example pls? I don't know what you mean by the "complimentarity" of the two.

Comment: Example papers: "An Inquiry into the Possibility of Nonlocal Quantum
Communication" http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.5098.pdf  ,  "Complementarity of one-particle and two-particle interference" http://www.academia.edu/1002375/Complementarity_of_one-particle_and_two-particle_interference (waaay too complicated), and really, by just writing the "Complementarity of one-particle and two-particle interference" in the Google, it's easy to find more sources about it, although they are quite advanced mathematically unfortunately.